# Find the largest number used in the sum

Tags: number-theory

The sum of ten positive odd numbers is $20$. Some numbers may repeat find the largest number that is used in this sum.

What I did so far:

$1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 = 22$

$22$ is not the number which the problem is looking for. Please help.

Comment: ...your attempt is quite faulty.  You fail to use ten positive odd numbers...

Comment: You make the biggest number big by making all of the other numbers small.  The smallest that the other numbers can be is 1, so suppose that you have nine ones.  What is left?

Comment: @XanderHenderson is you have 9 1's so you would have 1 x 9 = 9. Since you need to get to 20 you would subtract 20 - 9 = 11. So 11 would be left. So 11 is the answer?

Comment: Yes!  That is correct.

Comment: Don't edit posts when you find your solution the point of the site is to keep the questions and answers so it may help other people.

Comment: 10 is not an odd number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

In order to get the largest odd number, you'll want to use something along the lines of

$$\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_9+x=20$$

You want to find what $x$ is.

Comment: and then +1+1+1+...